# Javascript Alert is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I working on a simple JavaScript code and having some trouble getting my alert to display from my code. From what I understand the script should cause an alert box to pop up and display.

Here is the HTML:

[image]

Comment: It's not getting element `a` and `b`. Because you haven't specified any id on both elements.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your code, but include the code itself.

Comment: Please include code, don't post screenshots. Also, in your code - the "id" fields are not being found and hence `a` and `b` are getting nothing. Because of this you're not getting alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
    The problem is you have not assign any id or anything to get the value. Here is the code ,please try this.



   <input type = "text" value = "" id="input1" name="" >
      <input type = "text" value = ""   id="input2" name="" >
      <button  onClick="add()"> Add </button>

           function add()
    {
       var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
       var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
       alert(parseInt(input1) + parseInt(input2));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify ID in the input tags then try to call the alert using JS.